# Should I pass a list to this method or one by by one?

Tags: architecture, software-design

I'm currently TDD'ing my way through a little application, and came across something I don't know how to solve. The application lets people select drivers they think will finish at a certain position. The page will be built in ASP.NET.

My test:

```
[Test]
public void SubmitPrediction()
{
    Prediction prediction = new Prediction();

    Dictionary<int, string> selectedDrivers = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        {1, "Michael Schumacher"},
        {2, "Jensen Button"}
    };

    prediction.SubmitPrediction(selectedDrivers);
}
```

For now, I'm passing to `SubmitPrediction()` selectedDrivers, ***but***, I can also pass the position (integer), and the driverId (also int, will probably be replaced with an object called Driver which will have everything associated with a driver):

```
prediction.SubmitPrediction(1, "Michael Schumacher");
```

Will probably be:

```
prediction.SubmitPrediction(1, driver);
```

What I am wondering is which is the better approach. It might even be better to encapsulate the driver and the position in one class, but I can't come up with a decent name. Prediction is already taken in the meaning that it has a bunch of selected drivers and their positions. Then I could make the Dictionary a List.

```
prediction.SubmitPrediction(SomeEncapsulatedClassHere);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your requirements.  I think, there is no straight answer that works for everything, especially for a problem like a parameter type decision. You should understand the real problem you are trying to solve, existing behind the code problem. Don't make beautiful design your goal. I am strong adept of emergent design. Form follows function. Implementing your scenario with no bugs is your goal. Good design will have less bugs, but if you feel you don't have enough experience, just try things out, test different solutions. Sometimes it is better to write code that does the job and refactor later, once you've clearly seen a drawback of your current solution. That's the benefit of TDD, actually the base for TDD: red, green, refactor.

Do you want to minimize the data traffic between the client and server, than use the object that requires the least memory, the driver id. How are you assigning those ids? In case the list gets updated could a new id mean a driver from the old list?

Comment: The driverId's will probably be generated automatically by some database. I know I shouldn't think ahead to much, but the user will have a couple of dropdownboxes to select from. The driverId will be the value (which you can't see).

Answer (score 1):

As per the question in the title, if you already contemplating such a question, then I would suggest passing a list. A list may contain only one item so it will work well in place of one-by-one method, the other way around will require changing your interfaces (or class signatures).

I'm also on board with encapsulating driver and the position in one class. The name? How about DriverPlacement?

PS: take everything with a grain of salt as I don't know your context

Comment: The user of the app will be able to select a bunch of drivers for different positions they think will finish on that position (Probably dropdownlists). Once submitted, I will then have a presenter class to get the values from the asp page. The selected drivers should be passed to the prediction class, and this is the part where I am stuck I could use a foreach loop in the presenter to pass the drivers/driverid to Prediction. I could also put them into a list and *then* pass them off to presenter... DriverPlacement, I like it :-)